# Multi Item Bootstrap 4 Carousel is not showing clean transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I probably need a step in the right direction as I'm not sure if this is a CSS transition issue or a Jquery issue.

I'm trying to implement the carousel listed here:

https://www.codeply.com/go/XPajZsz60p/bootstrap-4-responsive-carousel-4-slides-slide-one

But when I tried to implement it (see half way down the page under Recent Clients) and try to slide right, it does not have a smooth transition. The slide left works perfectly.

http://www.fordengineering.ca

When I slide right, the new icon appears almost immediately and covers over the whole slide.

Is this because I should be doing this on the bs.slid.carousel function instead of the bs.slide.carousel function in JQuery? Or is this because of a CSS issue?

Comment: Silly question. Why do you have all of that extra "stuff" inside the custom.js file? It looks like your using Bootstrap's carousel and you should just need the  `$('.carousel').carousel();` piece

Comment: I'm trying to append the carousel so it shows 4 items at a time instead of just 1 single item

Comment: My instinct would be it's a css issue since it's the actual animation that appears to be messed up. It might be useful to compare what you changed from the codeply example.